# Code related to little endian

Tags: output, endianness

Assume the machine has little endian architecture and give the output

```
int a[]={0x4142,0x0044,0x4441,0x0044};
      char *b;
      b=(char *)a;
      printf(b);
```

I am not able to understand the output.

Answer (score 0):

An integer is usually 4 bytes, so the first value of `a` is `0x00004142`.

The machine is little endian, so if you read this value as a string, it is :
`0x42 (B) 0x41 (A) 0x00 (\0) 0x00`.

So the printed string is `BA`.

Be careful, the right syntax for printing out your string is : `printf("%s", b);` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)